# Swift Spritekit Scrolling Background

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, sprite-kit

I am trying to find the best method to do a vertically scrolling background in Swift,
without using the Update Method. The Background is 1 Image that should loop infinite.
The Image should be in the middle of the screen (full-size), moving down, and on top of that image should always be another image spawned.

However, mine doesn't work quite right, it spawns 2 images, and than after a delay they pop up and start the Actions again.
Also, it breaks sometimes down from 30 FPS to 26, which I want to avoid.
I hope somebody, who is more into Swift can help me.

```
let Background = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background.png")
    Background.filteringMode = .Nearest

    let BackgroundMove = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height, duration: 10)
    let BackgroundReset = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: self.frame.size.height, duration: 0.0)
    let BackgroundMoveAndResetForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([BackgroundMove,BackgroundReset]))

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 2.0 + self.frame.size.height / (Background.size().height * 2); ++i {
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: Background)
        sprite.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.frame.size.height)
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2 * i)
        sprite.zPosition = 1
        sprite.runAction(BackgroundMoveAndResetForever)
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the code I used to make a background that moves right to left across the screen. It used a loop to generate three backgrounds, all of which formed a line which passed through the screen and returned to their original position when they were done. To convert it to a screen that moves top to bottom, you would have to replace the `moveByX` SKActions to `moveToY`, and exchange changing x values with changing y values. Hope this helps!

```
func makeBackground() {

    var backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "img/bg.png")

    //move background right to left; replace
    var shiftBackground = SKAction.moveByX(-backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 9)
    var replaceBackground = SKAction.moveByX(backgroundTexture.size().width, y:0, duration: 0)
    var movingAndReplacingBackground = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([shiftBackground,replaceBackground]))

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i<3; i++ {
        //defining background; giving it height and moving width
        background=SKSpriteNode(texture:backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * i), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        background.size.height = self.frame.height
        background.runAction(movingAndReplacingBackground)

        self.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would you call this function from?

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. This would be called in SKGameScene, as soon as the game begins. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this one... It's probably not as short as it could be, but it only uses 2 copies of the image, unlike the one posted above as best-answer. It also allows you to specify a direction (true to scroll right, false to scroll left) and a speed (indicates how many seconds it takes for an image to scroll across the screen, lower numbers = faster). It requires you to specify the view as well, and I haven't tested it with images that aren't the same size as the desired output (although I included scaling, so it probably works)

```
func scrollingBackground (view: SKView, rightward: Bool, speed: CGFloat) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "space")
    let background2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "space")

    // variables to manage x position, will be set based on which
    // direction this will be moving
    var b1startX, b2startX, destination, resetPos: CGFloat

    // Set values based on desired direction
    if(rightward){
        b1startX = frame.size.width * -0.5      // value to start offscreen
        b2startX = frame.size.width * 0.5       // value to start on screen
        destination = frame.size.width * 1.5    // position where image will disappear
        resetPos = frame.size.width * -0.5      // position where image will reappear
    }
    else{
        b1startX = frame.size.width * 1.5
        b2startX = frame.size.width * 0.5
        destination = frame.size.width * -0.5
        resetPos = frame.size.width * 1.5
    }

    background.position = CGPoint(x: b1startX, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    background.scale(to: view.bounds.size)
    background.zPosition = -1

    background2.position = CGPoint(x: b2startX, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    background2.scale(to: view.bounds.size)
    background2.zPosition = -1

    // Define actions based on desired direction
    let scrollFromMid = SKAction.moveTo(x: destination, duration: TimeInterval(speed))
    let scrollFromLeft = SKAction.moveTo(x: destination, duration: TimeInterval(speed * 2.0))
    let resetPosition = SKAction.moveTo(x: resetPos, duration: 0)

    //background starts in the default starting position, totally offscreen
    background.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([scrollFromLeft, resetPosition])))

    // background2 starts fully displayed, moves offscreen, then into default loop
    background2.run(SKAction.sequence([scrollFromMid, resetPosition,
                    SKAction.repeatForever(
                        SKAction.sequence([scrollFromLeft, resetPosition]))
                    ]))

    addChild(background)
    addChild(background2)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create the BackgroundReset action you set the y change to a negative value, this will move the background further down the screen. Remove the minus sign to move the background back up the screen.

```
let BackgroundReset = 
SKAction.moveByX(0, y: /* removed minus sign here */ self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: 0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now It spawns infinite with a delay between them. How can I remove the delay?

Comment: change `self.frame.size.height * 2` in BackgroundMove and BackgroundReset to just `self.frame.size.height`?

Comment: I think I didn't express myself right. I added Information in the OP.

Comment: @Nima FYI, OP stands for original poster, a person. For this question, you are the OP.